Store user data in telegram bot conversation
I want to store user/conversation specific data for a telegram bot. Any ideas on how to do this? There is some sensitive data that only the user should have access to so I'm hesitant to store it in my db and would rather store it somewhere more local. I thought about storing it in a message or something and keeping track of the id, but I'm hoping there's a better way to do it. I'm using the Node.js node-telegram-bot-api npm package. Thanks!

Storing the data as a message and keeping the message id would only lead to exposing the information even further. This is because, once you stored the message ID, to retrieve the message content you might need to call copyMessage method or the forwardMessage method, both literally transfer the actual message to a new or existing chat.
So, the best way is to use a database. If the data is sensitive and you shouldn't peek as well, it's best to encrypt it with a standard encryption algorithm and store the encrypted data.
